# Baby weight after 1st month

Tags: newborn, weight

My baby boy was 3.780 kg (8.33 pounds) when he was born, and now after a month my wife and I We took him at pediatrician to weigh him and check is everything is ok.
So He is 5.500 (12.12 pounds) now, and I know it is a little more then I expect, but is it a normal for baby to gain almost 1.800 kg. What is your experience with this?
I think the reason is that he eats much more formula then his mother milk, (because the formula has much much more calories).

Thanks

Comment: You could consult growth charts: http://pediatrics.about.com/od/growthcharts2/a/who-growth-charts.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kids gain three times their birth weight and grow twice their birth length in their first year.  If the pediatrician isn't concerned, I wouldn't lose any sleep over it either. Infants are VERY good at self-regulating caloric intake to coincide with growth requirements (once you hit that first big growth spurt, you KNOW 'cause the kid WILL NOT want to sleep if the possibility of eating exists, and then 48-72 hours the sleep will rule, and then the clothes don't fit).

Both mine were majority formula-fed due to milk supply issues; my daughter was the first child our pediatrician had seen who didn't lose even an ounce of birth weight initially (most drop a few ounces the first few days).  Now at 5.5, she's at a perfectly normal weight for her height and age.

Comment: I remember my eldest's six-week growth spurt. He ate every 45 minutes for three days. We were exhausted. By the end of it, he had grown 1.5 inches! In three days!